# Batch File to process multiple pdfs one after another then delete them

Tags: windows, batch-file, pdf, jpeg

I have a batch file which takes a multi page pdf then converts each page into individual jpegs. This works by dragging the pdf onto the batch file. I now need to get this batch file to search for all pdfs in a directory and process each one at a time, deleting or moving the source pdf once the process is complete. This is the batch file so far. (Im using a Ghost script library as well)

```
echo off
echo.
echo.

set DPI=300
set ALPHABITS=2
set QUALITY=95
set FIRSTPAGE=1
set LASTPAGE=9999
REM MEMORY in MB
set MEMORY=300

set PDFFILE=%1
set JPGFILE=%PDFFILE:.pdf=-%%%d.jpg

set GS=%2
IF "%GS%" == "" (
    set GS="bin/gswin32c.exe"
    echo Loaded in 32bit mode
    echo.
)

%GS% -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile=%JPGFILE% -r%DPI% -dNOPAUSE -dFirstPage=%FIRSTPAGE% -dLastPage=%LASTPAGE% -dJPEGQ=%QUALITY% -dGraphicsAlphaBits=%ALPHABITS%  -dTextAlphaBits=%ALPHABITS%  -dNumRenderingThreads=4 -dBufferSpace=%MEMORY%000000  -dBandBufferSpace=%MEMORY%000000 -c %MEMORY%000000 setvmthreshold -f %PDFFILE% -c quit


move *.jpg "C:\ProgramData\EFI\EFI eXpress\Work\JobFolder\"
echo Finished.
pause
```

Im now getting this error

```
Error: /undefinedfilename in (Coffee)
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1195/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
GPL Ghostscript 9.14 (2014-03-26)
Copyright (C) 2014 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Error: /undefinedfilename in (Coffee)
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1195/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
GPL Ghostscript 9.14 (2014-03-26)
Copyright (C) 2014 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Error: /undefinedfilename in (OF)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work - though the two terms `"%%~na.jpg"` and `"%%a"` have double quotes to allow long filenames and I am only assuming the executable handles them correctly.

```
@echo off
echo.
echo.

set DPI=300
set ALPHABITS=2
set QUALITY=95
set FIRSTPAGE=1
set LASTPAGE=9999
REM MEMORY in MB
set MEMORY=300

set GS=%2
IF "%GS%" == "" (
    set GS="bin/gswin32c.exe"
    echo Loaded in 32bit mode
    echo.
)

md "done" 2>nul

for %%a in (*.pdf) do (

%GS% -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile="%%~na.jpg" -r%DPI% -dNOPAUSE -dFirstPage=%FIRSTPAGE% -dLastPage=%LASTPAGE% -dJPEGQ=%QUALITY% -dGraphicsAlphaBits=%ALPHABITS%  -dTextAlphaBits=%ALPHABITS%  -dNumRenderingThreads=4 -dBufferSpace=%MEMORY%000000  -dBandBufferSpace=%MEMORY%000000 -c %MEMORY%000000 setvmthreshold -f "%%a" -c quit

move "%%a" "done"
)

move *.jpg "C:\ProgramData\EFI\EFI eXpress\Work\JobFolder\"
echo Finished.
pause
```

Comment: actually just noticed that the outputted file is being over written each time. i think %%~na is the culprit. how can i add 1, 2, 3 to the outputted file names so it isnt overwritten each time?

Comment: If you run it in a folder with one pdf file, what files does it generate? `gswin32c.exe` should be adding 1,2,3 to each page.

Comment: just the one file which seems to be over written each time. I never get out more than one file

Comment: Your original script used `-%%%d` and I couldn't see why that was there but it would seem now to be a counter that `gswin32c.exe` maintains.  Replace the `"%%~na.jpg"` with `"%%~na-%%%d.jpg"` and see how it works.  You may have to reduce the `%%%d` to `%%d` or `%d` but trialing each version will show you which one to use.  Test it with one pdf file until you sort out the right syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and it might work for you:

```
echo off
echo.
echo.

set DPI=300
set ALPHABITS=2
set QUALITY=95
set FIRSTPAGE=1
set LASTPAGE=9999
REM MEMORY in MB
set MEMORY=300

set JPGFILE=%PDFFILE:.pdf=-%%%d.jpg

set GS=%2
IF "%GS%" == "" (
    set GS="bin/gswin32c.exe"
    echo Loaded in 32bit mode
    echo.
)

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.pdf') do %GS% -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile=%JPGFILE% -r%DPI% -dNOPAUSE -dFirstPage=%FIRSTPAGE% -dLastPage=%LASTPAGE% -dJPEGQ=%QUALITY% -dGraphicsAlphaBits=%ALPHABITS%  -dTextAlphaBits=%ALPHABITS%  -dNumRenderingThreads=4 -dBufferSpace=%MEMORY%000000  -dBandBufferSpace=%MEMORY%000000 -c %MEMORY%000000 setvmthreshold -f %%a -c quit


move *.jpg "C:\ProgramData\EFI\EFI eXpress\Work\JobFolder\"
echo Finished.
pause
```